# how to embed form into html document with css

Tags: forms, embed

I am trying to input a form into my html and when I view the page, I don't see the entire form, just the start of the form. The code is below of my html and form script.

```
<section id="content">
        <div class="container_12">
            <article class="a3">
                <h4>Careers</h4>
                    <p class="p2">

                           <a name="form1160016477" id="formAnchor1160016477"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fs23.formsite.com/include/form/embedManager.js?1160016477"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
EmbedManager.embed({
    key: "http://fs23.formsite.com/res/showFormEmbed?EParam=m%2FOmK8apOTB8lIDHQTyQ62rYe2Y6sJfY&1160016477",
    width: "100%"

});
</script>
<!-- Notes: 
To control the width of the form, change width: "100%" to any number or percentage.
To pre-populate fields in the form or to use a custom resize callback, see http://fs23.formsite.com/documentation/embedded-form.html
-->
```

Here is the website: http://www.creativemindspcs.org/englishapplication.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the iframe height, you need to add `height:800px`; to the iframe style in the html. At the moment it is set at the default which is too small so the iframe window doesn't show everything.

As the iframe is generated dynamically with the JavaScript it should be possible to pass in a height parameter like you do width, if that is the case then this would fix it:

```
EmbedManager.embed({
     key: "http://fs23.formsite.com/res/showFormEmbed?    EParam=m%2FOmK8apOTB8lIDHQTyQ62rYe2Y6sJfY&1160016477",
    width: "100%",
    height: "800px"
});
```

If te 800px doesn't fix it you could try 100% for height but generally speaking heights and percents don't mix very well.

Comment: So you are saying to add <br clear="all" /> to my css file or my html file?

Comment: thank you. I have tried both and they still don't work.sorry to be so dense.  http://www.creativemindspcs.org/englishapplication.html

Answer (score 0):

i have recently had to implement this and the forms now support `resizeCallback`, so you can set height via javascript

https://fs8.formsite.com/documentation/embedded-form.html